# angular routes not working in nginx docker container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

We have an angular app that we are trying to run in docker nginx:alpine
So far everything as working 100% including ssl with redirect from 80, but we cannot get the angular routing to work. It keeps going to 404 if we try to go somewhere directly.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.localhost;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name *.localhost;
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

           # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't

           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

           # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days

           add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
           add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
           add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
           return 204;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }
}
```

it has been a struggle getting everything to work as it should since i have never build an nginx image from scratch, especially not with ssl.

**EDIT:**
After multiple more tries. If i add

```
location /login {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

then on the login page i can refresh it and it works.
By all means this takes me to believe that location / is not working for everything. I really do not want to add a location for each route as the app has a few thousands

Comment: Your container needs to support single page app redirection, please check this out for example: https://github.com/steebchen/nginx-spa or https://github.com/carlosflorencio/docker-nginx-static-spa

Comment: i tried their way and their image it doesn't work

Comment: I also did not try both images, just gave you a direction... In general, in case of angular routing, NGINX needs to understand that this is not NGINX defined routing, and redirect it back to index.html. I personally serve my static Angular files with custom node JS server. Check this also: https://dev.to/hoverbaum/dockerizing-spas-2lc9#empowering-spa-capabilities

Answer (score 2):

Under "location /" change

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

to

```
try_files $uri /index.html;
```